# Turn list of strings with mixed inherent types into inherent type

Tags: python, list, types

So I have a list of strings, each of which have inherent types.

```
mixedbag = ['True', '2.7', '3', 'Ninety']
```

I want to transform this to look like this:

```
[True, 2.7, 3, 'Ninety']
```

What I thought of is to create a large try/except chain to evaluate each item in the list, but that doesn't feel like a pythonic way of handling this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) in a try-except block.

```
from ast import literal_eval
def unmix(ele):
    try:
        ele = literal_eval(ele)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return ele
```

---

**Demo**

```
>>> list(map(unmix, mixedbag))
[True, 2.7, 3, 'Ninety']
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `ast.literal_eval` function:

```
import ast
mixedbag = ['True', '2.7', '3', 'Ninety']

evaled = []
for i in mixedbag:
    try:
        evaled.append(ast.literal_eval(i))
    except ValueError:
        evaled.append(i)

print(evaled)
```

The output:

```
[True, 2.7, 3, 'Ninety']
```